# how to create this type of plot by 'ggplot2'

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgLOC.png - this is what i want to draw

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2YfL.png - this is data of this plot

Comment: Please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, you're more likely to get help if you show a reasonable attempt at obtaining at least a partial solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but the essence.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(
  type = c("barley",
           "maize",
           "sunlower oil",
           "wheat"),
  ukraine = c(0.974, 0.1643, 0.4221, 0.0891),
  russia = c(0.095, 0.0160, 0.2140, 0.1420)
)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  type         ukraine russia
  <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>
1 barley        0.974   0.095
2 maize         0.164   0.016
3 sunlower oil  0.422   0.214
4 wheat         0.0891  0.142

df %>%  
  gather(-type, key = "country", value = "value") %>%  
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = type, y = value, fill = country) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

ggplot2 is basically used to create elegant data visualization using graphics.

Here is example:

```
library(ggplots2) 
ggplot2(dataset, aes(x='dataset_col1', y='dataset_col2')
```

here we get output of `dataset_col1 (x axis)` and `dataset_col2(y-axis)`

Before running this code, you need to download the package -> ggplot2 from the packages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).